# Import Python module (from another path) and use as default

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I want to import requests module which is located at another path.
I want to use below code. Also I could see the requests directory where the module is installed has bunch of other files. What are this needed for.

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Below are some of the contents of /Requests dir.

```
adapters.py
adapters.pyc
api.py
__init__.py
```

......

Below question has some great answer, but still confuses me.

[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to include the .py file. Python interpretor looks at the path mentioned for **init**.py file. If it's there the code should work fine. Though for Python 3 **init**.py file is also not required.

As I can see in the directory listing of yours **init**.py file is there. Also note **init**.pyc file is there, it's just the cache version of above.

To see all the paths that interpretor would be referring to do below

```
import sys
sys.path
```

What you are using here is

```
sys.path.append('/.../requests/')
```

Don't use the extra '/' after the requests, it means it's looking for requests directory in requests folder and gives you the error No module named requests.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't simple

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path\\to\\request_module')
```

solve your problem?

Comment: I get the below error when I do import requests, `import sys, sys.path.append('/.../requests/')` do i need to explicity mention .py file also
`ImportError: No module named requests`